How to check if user cannot send messages (was restricted or muted) in telegram chat by telethon api?
Here is a part of my code:
permissions = await client.get_permissions(event.chat_id, user.id)
                    InsertNewUserInDB(user.id, user.username, permissions.is_admin, permissions.is_muted, permissions.is_banned)

There is many func's in Documentation and I easily can check if user is admin or is banned. But how can I easily get property that user is muted or restricted? Because I can edit permissions by func await edit_permissions(... send_messages: bool = True...)→ Updates
Method for editing permission description
Permissions that you can get through method "get_par...permissions"

Your code is correct to begin with. In v1, get_permissions returns ParticipantPermissions which contains what the user can do.

@Lonami Yeah, but there isn't any chance to pull permission that's give info about person was muted. In Telethon you can pull only info about ban that is bool type and works on mute too. So if chat user rights were restricted in any way you will get is_banned as True, but you can't understand if he is really banned (left the chat) or just can't send massages for example.

I solves this by adding aiogram in my solution. For starting the  bot, you should add it at the start of main.py file:
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher
from aiogram.types import ChatMemberRestricted, ChatMemberBanned

bot = Bot(token=config('API_TOKEN'))
dp = Dispatcher()

and then in handler, you should use:
for user in users:
        if user.username == None:
            user.username = str(user.id)
        permissions = await client.get_permissions(event.chat_id, user.id)
        member = await bot.get_chat_member(event.chat_id, user.id)
        is_admin = permissions.is_admin
        is_muted = isinstance(member, ChatMemberRestricted)
        is_banned = isinstance(member, ChatMemberBanned)

